# Is it worth it to use Array.map just to avoid indexing?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code snippet:

```
function getMaxAge(arr, id, max) {
  let found = false
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const val = arr[i];
    if (val.id === id) {
      found = true
      if (max > val.age) val.age = max
    }
    return val
  })

  if (found === false) {
    arr.push({
      id: id,
      age: max
    })
  }
  return arr
}
```

Now watch the same logic using map:

```
function getMaxAge(arr, id, max) {
  let found = false
  arr = arr.map((val, index) => {
    if (val.id === id) {
      found = true
      if (max > val.age) val.age = max
    }
    return val
  })

  if (found === false) {
    arr.push({
      id: id,
      age: max
    })
  }
  return arr
}
```

What I am interested in is not the logic of the function, but whether the use of `Array.map` is justified for this scenario?

Comment: These will do two different things. The function in `map` will return from the callback (and return undefined for values that aren't `awesome`) for each item in the list. The loop will return from the outer function on the first `awesome` value it finds.

Comment: Yes, but if they are called within some function ... as far as the caller is concerned, they both return the same value.

Comment: Not at all. The first code will return a (single) array to the caller. In contrast, the second code will create an array of arrays, and will *not* return to the caller.

Comment: As already mentioned, that the edit does not address, the return from a for loop will return out of whatever function the for loop is inside.  The return in the `map()` will simply return the value to the array created by `map()`.  Which will not be returned out of the function **unless** you also put a return statement in from of the call to map.

Comment: Seems like you're looking for `indexOf` eg `let index = arr.indexOf('awesome'); if (index >= 0) return [arr[index], index];`

Comment: putting return debate aside, what is your criteria for "best practice"? code readability, performance, something else...?

Comment: Yes, you guys are right ... I have corrected it now ... what I wanted to ask is whether the cost of calling .map (which creates another copy) is worth the effort of typing arr[i]?

Comment: What your doing in your map function is called a side effect.  It usually means your doing something wrong.  Your not actually using your map result for anything, your just looping with it.  The easiest way to know if you did it right, did you use the return value of the map function? No? Then you probably don't need a map function.

Comment: I don't think you understand what map is doing. Map still does 'indexing' in the sense that its internal implementation still has a `for` loop inside of it.

Comment: It sounds like you're simply looking for [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4zd719wa/  random snippet using the original version and a version using `find()`.

Comment: It defiantly seems like .map is not the correct solution to this problem. It seems like you could replace your for loop with arr.forEach, or simply using arr.indexOf. Also if your looking for an object you can use arr.find

Answer (score 0):

I personally avoid manual iteration whenever possible. Iterator methods are a concept build upon manual iteration and let objects themself decide how iteration is done. So if you have the option, I'd say avoid manual iteration. There are a few things to keep in mind.

Generally speaking I would avoid iteration methods when altering the collection while iterating. Because you don't know the implementation you don't fully know what's happening when adding/removing elements to the collection during iteration.

When you explicitly need to work with the index (and not the element) it might be worth the trouble to manually do iteration.

With the above being said, it's good to know what iteration methods are available to you, since different methods fulfil different tasks. Knowing which method to use in which scenario will result in better performance and cleaner code.

Taking your example I'd change it to the following:

```
function getMaxAge(arr, id, max) {
  arr = arr.slice();
  const matchesId = arr.filter(val => val.id == id),
        found = matchId.length;

  matchesId.filter(val => val.age < max)
           .forEach(val => (val.age = max));

  if (!found) arr.push({id: id, age: max});
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if we add your question in comment
*"what I wanted to ask is whether the cost of calling .map (which creates another copy) is worth the effort of typing arr[i]?"* to the original question and assume you're in dilemma between iterating functions vs. manual iteration in a for loop with respect to performance, then i guess we could answer roughly like this:

1. for small arrays - it doesn't matter.
2. for big arrays - for loop is definitely better

for big arrays and critical performance (where you want to keep your code below some fps threshold time), you'll want to pay attention to many different things: caching variable values (`arr.length` for example), do object pooling whenever possible, offload work to background workers, etc...

but have on mind saying that *premature optimization is the root of all evil*. in other words, start with most readable functions (using them properly, of course :P ) and optimize as needed for particular cases you need.